# Shifting from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: drivers, partitioning, windows-7, ntfs, swap

First of all I know that there are many questions like this, same topic, but I have some confusions, I will explain them in details

my computer

http://www.mediafire.com/view/f6drfnivlmwgmyx/Untitled2.png

4gb DDR3 RAM,1 TB HDD,Pentium g 2.6ghz / 2.6ghz, Asus motherboard

Now I know how to install Ubuntu and what to do etc, I googled for hours, watched youtube tutorials and finally I'm on track but I got some confusions:

1st,

this is my partitions right now

http://www.mediafire.com/view/1sjbfx0njn4xlcq/Untitled(2).png

I got 3 partitions, two are 390gb each ntfs & one is 149 gb ntfs where Windows is installed, now i want to install Ubuntu on 149gb partition but I don't want to even touch the other twos,

When i install Ubuntu I will go to "Something Else" option,

Question: Can I keep them even if I go to this option?

now if I format my 149gb partition, I will use ext4 and i will use " / " as a mount point and will select primary, but there is another option "Location for new partition"

Question: which option should I select ? beginning or end ? and explain them please :)

NOTE:

> I will completely erase the windows 7, I'm NOT DUAL BOOTING

After it, I will create another partition for swap, how much should I give it ?

[NOTE: i got 1 tb so giving some gbs to swap wont be an issue, i only want my pc to be fast thats all]

and what will happen to my two 390gb partitions? I don't want to lose them.

and after i successfully install ubuntu, how im gonna install these drivers ?

intel HD graphics / realtek HD audio manager / etc etc

http://www.mediafire.com/view/8xa3a0bkxoxia4s/Untitled3.png

NOTE: there was a drivers cd with my motherboard box, will it run on linux ?

In short, I'm just worried about the other partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got 3 partitions, two are 390gb each ntfs & one is 149 gb ntfs where Windows is installed, now i want to install Ubuntu on 149gb partition but I don't want to even touch the other twos,

This is certainly possible, and it's a reasonable short-term course of action; however:

- There's always the risk of accidentally damaging or destroying one or both of those partitions, because of user error, a bug, a hardware failure, etc. ***Back up important user data before proceeding!!***
- In the long term, using NTFS on a Linux-only system is unwise. Linux lacks NTFS repair tools, so the moment you do an unclean shutdown or the filesystem develops a fault, you won't be able to fix it except by booting a Windows emergency disk. Furthermore, the way Ubuntu provides read/write access to NTFS is through a driver that's slow, compared to the standard Linux filesystem drivers.

Thus, I recommend you develop a plan to migrate entirely to ext4fs (or some other Linux filesystem, such as XFS or Btrfs). You have plenty of space in which to do this, so the only question is how. Generally, Linux users store all their data in their home directories under `/home`, so one possibility would be to create a ~30GiB root (`/`) partition, a ~5GiB swap partition (see below), and a `/home` partition in the space occupied by your Windows `C:` partition, then copy the data over from `D:` to `/home`, delete `D:`, expand `/home`, and repeat for `E:`. This might be a tight fit, so you might need to temporarily move some stuff from `D:` to `E:`, but this is probably the way to go. (In fact, you might want to move stuff from `D:` to `E:` in Windows before you wipe it. That will give you the option of deleting `D:` from the start, and moving those files in Windows will be slightly safer than moving them in Ubuntu, should that be necessary.) You could modify this plan in various ways if you wanted.

> now if I format my 149gb partition, I will use ext4 and i will use " / " as a mount point and will select primary, but there is another option "Location for new partition"
>
> Question: which option should I select ? beginning or end ? and explain them please :

The beginning/end question is relevant only if you create a partition that's smaller than the available free space; it tells the partitioner whether to put that new partition at the beginning or end of the free space, leaving the remaining free space after or before, respectively, the new partition.

Note that for the migration plan I've proposed, it's important that the `/home` partition fall at the end of the initial Ubuntu space, so that it can be easily expanded into the space used by your current `D:` and `E:` partitions.

> After it, I will create another partition for swap, how much should I give it ?

Traditionally, swap space has been about twice your RAM. These days it's rare to need that much swap space. The most common use for lots of swap space is if you use a computer's suspend-to-disk feature, in which case you need at least as much swap space as you have RAM. That's why I suggested ~5GiB of swap space; with 4GiB of RAM, that gives you a little margin for error when specifying the size and you'll still be able to suspend to disk. If you don't plan to *ever* suspend to disk, you can get by with even less swap space. Some people don't use any at all, although I don't recommend going to that extreme because the kernel can use swap space to optimize performance if your RAM needs rise and then fall back down.

> and after i successfully install ubuntu, how im gonna install these drivers ?
>
> intel HD graphics / realtek HD audio manager / etc etc

You don't normally need to worry about that; the Linux kernel and related tools (such as Xorg) include drivers. You only need to install extra drivers if you've got bleeding-edge hardware or if you want advanced features available in manufacturer-provided drivers for some hardware, such as ATI/AMD or Nvidia video cards.

> NOTE: there was a drivers cd with my motherboard box, will it run on linux ?

It *might* include Linux drivers; but if so, they're probably just older versions of drivers that come with Ubuntu already, so you might as well put that drivers CD in the circular file.

Comment: thanks for answering, it cleared all of my thoughts, tttttttttthaaaaaaaaaaaaaaankkks !

Comment: will ubuntu 14.04.2 support my motherboard ? Asus p8h61-m-le i was searching there site but didnt find anything on linux, they were only talking about windows os

Comment: Few motherboard manufacturers explicitly support Linux, but most models do work fine. Try a Web search on "Linux ASUS P8H61-M-LE" or something similar to find user reports. A few manufacturers of complete computers work with Canonical to certify their hardware; see [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) for information on that program, including links to lists of certified hardware.

Comment: i googled and found it , ASUS P8H61-M-LE will run ubuntu 10.0 so it wont be a problem running 14.04, btw i checked your website, i didnt knew that im talking to a genius :) you wrote 25 books on linux amazing :)

https://www.asus.com/websites/global/aboutasus/OS/Linux.pdf